# Unable to connect Mongo Db from Spring Application

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mvc

I am trying to connect mongo db from spring application and i m getting the following error

Unable to connect to any servers; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoServerSelectionException: Unable to connect to any servers

DAO Code:

```
 productList = mongoTemplate.findAll(PSAProduct.class, GSM_STATS_PSA3);
```

Mongo DB Template:

```
public class MongoDBTemplate 
{
    static String MONGO_SERVER_IP;
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
    private static final org.slf4j.Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProductController.class);



    public static @Bean MongoTemplate getTemplate(String databaseName) 
    { 
        MongoDBTemplate mongoDBTemplate=new MongoDBTemplate();
        try
        {
            mongoDBTemplate.mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoClient("172.16.19.261:27017"), databaseName));
        }catch(Exception ee)
        {
            ee.printStackTrace();
        }
        return mongoDBTemplate.mongoTemplate; 
    } 
}
```

Stacktrace :

```
31804 [http-8080-1] ERROR com.teledna.pms.dao.psa.PSADao - Exception Occured while fetching entity count from DAO  Unable to connect to any servers; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoServerSelectionException: Unable to connect to any servers
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Unable to connect to any servers; nested exception is com.mongodb.MongoServerSelectionException: Unable to connect to any servers
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(MongoExceptionTranslator.java:64)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.potentiallyConvertRuntimeException(MongoTemplate.java:1665)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1548)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.findAll(MongoTemplate.java:1062)
    at com.teledna.pms.dao.psa.PSADao.getPSA2Product(PSADao.java:44)
    at com.teledna.pms.service.psa.PSAService.getPSA2Product(PSAService.java:39)
    at com.teledna.pms.controller.PSAController.getPSA2Product(PSAController.java:40)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:623)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:219)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:746)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:925)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:915)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:811)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:796)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:713)
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoServerSelectionException: Unable to connect to any servers
    at com.mongodb.BaseCluster.getDescription(BaseCluster.java:112)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.getClusterDescription(DBTCPConnector.java:401)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.getType(DBTCPConnector.java:574)
    at com.mongodb.DBTCPConnector.isMongosConnection(DBTCPConnector.java:375)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.isMongosConnection(Mongo.java:645)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor._check(DBCursor.java:454)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor._hasNext(DBCursor.java:546)
    at com.mongodb.DBCursor.hasNext(DBCursor.java:571)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate.executeFindMultiInternal(MongoTemplate.java:1534)
    ... 33 more
```

Comment: can you connect to your `mongod` server from `mongo` command ?

Comment: Why ae you first creating a `MongoTemplate` without any settings and afterwards replace it. Why is your method `static` it shouldn't be.

Comment: Ah now i get the contraption it is because it is static... Remove the `static` and just return `new MongoTemplate(....)` from the method. Also you probably want the beans needed to be spring beans as well to allow them to be properly started and destroyed.

Comment: @Harsh Patel Yah..I was able to connect ...but through the application I m not able to connect

Comment: @M. Deinum  I tried with non static.. still same error i am getting...

Answer (score 0):

try to create

```
@Bean
public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() throws MongoException, UnknownHostException {
    MongoDbFactory factory = new SimpleMongoDbFactory(new MongoURI(env.getProperty("mongo_uri.dev")));
    return factory;
}
```

and the mongo mongo_uri is in the format:

`mongo_uri.heroku=mongodb://user:pass@ds037097.mongolab.com:37097/heroku_app13338532`

create your MongoTemplate in that way:

```
mongoDBTemplate.mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
```